# How does jQuery.sap.require work?

Tags: sapui5

Does SAPUI5 load the libraries each time I call `jQuery.sap.require("someLibrary")`? 
For instance if I am calling the above statement in multiple modules in my application, is "someLibrary" loaded multiple times also?

Comment: `jQuery.sap.require` is deprecated. [Use `sap.ui.define` / `sap.ui.require` instead.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45277948/5846045)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lib is only loaded once. You can find this information in the SDK
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/ModularizationConcept.html

> **Module Loading**
>
> As mentioned already, modules are loaded by calling function jQuery.sap.require with the name of a required module. The framework then checks whether the named module is loaded already. If so, the function simply returns. Otherwise it tries to load and execute the module synchronously. If any of these two steps fails, an exception is thrown and execution of the calling module thereby is disrupted.

Comment: so, it is ok to load the libraries winthin the application.js file (as described in the best practices recommendation) would that boost the user experience since now I have some pages in my application that require many modules and when the user clicks on the tile (to access the page) the app halts for a second!

Answer (score 4):

In case someone still considers to use `jQuery.sap.require`, be aware that it sends only synchronous XHRs which should be avoided.

> The use of `jQuery.sap.require` is **synchronous** and considered as "bad practice" because syncXHR is [deprecated](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#sync-warning) by the Web Hypertext Application Technology Working Group. (Source: [*Modules and Dependencies*](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/91f23a736f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070))

Instead, the current best practice is to use [`sap.ui.define` or `.require`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui) for **asynchronous** module loading:

```html
<!-- Enable asynchronous module loading in index.html (available since 1.58.2) -->
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="..." data-sap-ui-async="true" ...>
```

```js
sap.ui.define([ // or .require
  // modules to load
], function(/* modules available once loaded */) {
  // ...
});
```

[image: Asynchronification of module dependency]
<sup>Source: [Asynchronify Your App](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/04/26/ui5ers-buzz-29-asynchronify-your-app/) by Arnd vom Hofe. Note: [anonymous `sap.ui.define` can be called **only once** at top-level.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62584795/5846045)</sup>

Same as `jQuery.sap.require`, the API `sap.ui.require([/*...*/])` fetches the modules also only once depending on their internal states.

For more information, please take a look at the topics under [*Modules and Dependencies*](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/91f23a736f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070).

---

Sync XHR is deprecated not only by the web platform generally, but will be also replaced by UI5 gradually with a new set of APIs.

[image: Deprecation of Sync XHR]
<sup>Source: [UI5 Evolution](https://de.slideshare.net/PeterMuessig1/ui5-evolution-77465160) by Peter Muessig</sup>

Consequently, **`jQuery.sap.require` and `jQuery.sap.declare` are now [deprecated](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/7af85a55854fa7ec7ff0fabbc575175a7e4b3b80) and will be removed in the next major UI5 version** (aka. *["Legacy-free UI5"](https://youtu.be/QYQxjgwVtCI?t=1702)*)**!**

Answer (score 1):

The libraries are loaded once. This can be seen in the network tab in chrome developer tools.

Also check the documentation as pointed by cevou here:

- https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/91f23a736f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070

Answer (score 1):

When you call this function with some library, it checks that given library is loaded or not using associative array. If the library is loaded, then it returns `null`. And if the library is not loaded, then it loads the library using sjax call and after a success of the sjax call, it sets the library name as key into associative array.