# Setting busy states when loading modules doesn't work

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I want to load the third-party module on the click of the `sap.m.Button`. As the library takes a little time for loading, I want to show the view busy. But it is not working. I want to load the third-party module, and after loading and executing the functionality of the module, I want to set the view busy to `false`.

Controller:

```js
onPressDownload: function () {
  var view = this.getView();
  view.setBusy(true);
  jQuery.sap.require('pdfmake.build.pdfmake');
  jQuery.sap.require('pdfmake.build.vfs_fonts');
  if (pdfMake) {
    var docDef = "";
    pdfMake.createPdf(docDef).download();
    view.setBusy(false);
  }
},
```

View:

```js
var oBtn = new sap.m.Button({
  press: [oController.onPressDownload, oController]
});
```

As `jQuery.sap.require` makes a synchronous call, `view.setBusy` should work. But it is not working as expected, and `view.setBusy()` resets immediately to `false`. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

All controls (including Views) provide `busyIndicatorDelay` with the default value of `1000` ms. I.e. if the latency is shorter than 1 second, the app won't display the busy indicator anyway. One second is the recommended delay by Fiori design guideline.<sup>[src](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/busy-state/#use-the-busy-state-of-the-control-if)</sup> You can reduce it to `0` ms. However, That **won't solve the actual problem** either because..:

### Real Issue

> As `jQuery.sap.require` makes a synchronous call, `view.setBusy` should work.

Unfortunately, it's the other way around. **Because** it makes a synchronous call, handling busy state can't work as intended since synchronous requests freeze the main thread / event loop of the browser completely. I.e.:

```js
control.setBusy(true);
// <synchronous calls>;
control.setBusy(false);
```

is the **same as**

```js
control.setBusy(true);
control.setBusy(false);
```

Please **stop using the deprecated `jQuery.sap.require`** function and replace it with either `sap.ui.require` or add the dependency to the `sap.ui.define` at the top.

```js
onPressDownload: function() {
  this.getView().setBusy(true);
  sap.ui.require([ // Instead of jQuery.sap.require("...")
    "pdfmake/build/pdfmake",
    "pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts",
  ], function(/*...*/) {
    // ...
    this.getView().setBusy(false);
  }.bind(this));
},
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45277948/5846045

The API `sap.ui.require` can be used to fetch modules / JS files asynchronously on-demand.

---

⚠️ Please make sure to enable asynchronous loading of modules in *index.html* when bootstrapping:

```js
// since 1.58.2
data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core, sap.m, ..."
data-sap-ui-async="true" // replaces preload="async" and xx-async="true"
```

```js
// for 1.58.1 and below
data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core, sap.m, ..."
data-sap-ui-preload="async"
data-sap-ui-xx-async="true"
```

If those settings are missing, JS files will still be loaded synchronously!

Comment: Hi @Boghyon Hoffmann, I tried this, but it didn't work out. the second file `vfs_fonts` have a size around of 30mb. So on clicking a button, after 10-11 seconds, the view gets busy and then after executing the code inside function, view is set to false. It there anything I need to do so I get view busy after clicking  a button until the view busy sets to false?

Comment: @SuhasBhattu So the busy indicator **does** get displayed now, but the next issue is that it gets displayed only after around 10 sec, right? Does it happen even with the decreased `busyIndicatorDelay`? Are those two files still fetched synchronously or asynchronously (in parallel)? What is the current UI5 version the app is running with? Have you added `data-sap-ui-async="true"` in _index.html_? Please make sure that there aren't any other synchronous requests when `onPressDownload` is executed.

Comment: Hi @Boghyan Hoffmann, apologies for the delay in answering. It works for `data-sap-ui-async="true"`. There's one thing for the `busyIndicatorDelay` is that I am trying to set the negative number so that view gets busy earlier. But it doesn't seem working out.

Comment: @SuhasBhattu Do you still have the same issue? Let us know if you could solve the problem. Otherwise, I don't think we can help much here with the given information.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me

```
onPressDownload: function () {
    var view = this.getView();
    view.setBusyIndicatorDelay(0);
    view.setBusy(true);
    setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery.sap.require('pdfmake.build.pdfmake');
        jQuery.sap.require('pdfmake.build.vfs_fonts');
        if (pdfMake) {
            var docDef = "";
            pdfMake.createPdf(docDef).download();
            view.setBusy(false);
       }
    }, 0);
}
```