# "Modules that use an anonymous define() call must be loaded with a require() call"

Tags: sapui5, amd

In the [walkthrough step 7: JSON Model](https://github.com/SAP/openui5-docs/blob/d1d5565d68f2c0aa85b512217ddd8ab588e82fed/docs/Step_7_JSON_Model_70ef981.md#webappindexhtml) example, the app apparently works as documented but I see the following error in the console:

> Error: Modules that use an anonymous define() call must be loaded with a require() call; they must not be executed via script tag or nested into other modules.

The only other instance of this message that I could find seems, to my untrained eye, to deal with a wholly [different scenario](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2203).

I've tried both Firefox and Chromium, CDN hosting vs local hosting, two different UI5 versions (1.77.0 and 1.79.0), both minified and plain, so I'd suppose this is really something in the [code itself](https://github.com/AndreaBorgia-Abo/tutorial_openui5/tree/116d3067eaadcd3b3be264e6719dc34dae9b6d4e/com.myorg.helloworld).

What could it be? Also, is it something I can safely ignore and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Anonymous `define`

Calling `sap.ui.define([...],...)` defines a module *anonymously* because the 1st argument is not a string (*module name* or *module ID*) but a list of the module's dependencies. If the module name is omitted, the framework automatically determines it based on how the module script was referenced.

- Use anonymous **`sap.ui.define` once at top-level** of the JS file content, not multiple times.
- Replace `sap.ui.define` with **`sap.ui.require` when simply requiring existing modules.**  See my comment at [Issue #2203 · SAP/openui5 (github.com)](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2203#issuecomment-420918457).
- Always address the module with the same registered module ID prefix consistently.* This avoids redundantly registering the same module with different module IDs which, in the anonymous `define` scenario, would otherwise cause processing the module definition multiple times due the framework determining the module ID from the different ID prefixes.

* Module ID prefixes can be registered with `data-sap-ui-resourceroots`, `sap.ui.loader.config`, or formerly with `jQuery.sap.registerModulePath`.

#### Named module `define`

The 1st argument in `sap.ui.define("my/demo/Module",[...] ,...)` defines the name of the module manually which **must** be passed when:

- Defining a nested module within an existing module definition in a single JS file content, which is, however, forbidden according to the `sap.ui.define` API description:

  > **A single file must not contain multiple calls to `sap.ui.define`.** [...]
- Defining a module which was initiated by a `<script>` tag from HTML.

The walkthrough is fixed with [`SAP/openui5@6302b8f`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/6302b8feff8270baba0e992d1887b1357afc54ce) and  [`SAP/openui5-docs#43`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5-docs/pull/43) accordingly.