# How do I detect cyclic dependent modules in UI5?

Tags: sapui5, amd

Given:

```js
sap.ui.define([ // in my/ModuleA.js
  // "...",
  "./ModuleB",
], function (/*...,*/ModuleB) {
  // ...             ModuleB is undefined here
  return/*...*/;
});
```

```js
sap.ui.define([ // in my/ModuleB.js
  // "...",
  "./ModuleA"
], function (/*...,*/ModuleA) {
  // ...             ModuleA is undefined here
  return/*...*/;
});
```

After building and running the application, inspecting the generated `Component-preload.js` shows that the `ModuleB` parameter in `my/ModuleA.js` or the `ModuleA` parameter in `my/ModuleB.js` is `undefined`.

It's easy to detect such cyclic dependencies in a small project. But how can I detect such flaws easily if there are multiple modules and their dependencies are complex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open the browser console and make sure to **enable viewing all "Verbose" logs.**
2. Run the application with the following **UI5 config parameter `sap-ui-xx-debugModuleLoading` with the value `true`**.
3. In the log, filter by "cycle detected".

   > <sup>**cycle detected** between 'my/ModuleB.js' and 'my/ModuleA.js', returning `undefined` for 'my/ModuleA.js' -  sap.ui.ModuleSystem</sup>
   > <sup>**cycle detected** between 'my/ModuleA.js' and 'my/ModuleB.js', returning `undefined` for 'my/ModuleB.js' -  sap.ui.ModuleSystem</sup>

   And since [`e7daa82`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/e7daa823647b1b0b1e6ed4e3bd088ed109f9f60b) (UI5 1.121), an actual error is logged with the message:

   > <sup>Dependency **cycle detected**:  [...] sap.ui.ModuleSystem.</sup>

### In UI5 library development

Initializing your library with the [API `initLibrary`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.core.Core#methods/initLibrary) from the required `"sap/ui/core/Core"` module is allowed only since UI5 **1.91** ([commit: `d83868e`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/d83868eaada1766a37a4da42b3b8e3ac797fd2fb)). In lower UI5 versions, the `"sap/ui/core/Core"` module might resolve to `undefined` if required early during the bootstrap process due to a cyclic dependency.

### Resolution

- Double-check if the dependency to the `ModuleA` or `ModuleB` is really necessary in the module definition itself. **If it's not used, remove the dependency from the list.**
- Follow the [**Best Practices for Loading Modules**](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/00737d6c1b864dc3ab72ef56611491c4) and its child topics from the documentation.

---

Related Q&A on resolving the error  *["Modules that use an anonymous define() call must be loaded with a require() call"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62581851/modules-that-use-an-anonymous-define-call-must-be-loaded-with-a-require-cal/62584795).*