# How to make UI5 content compatible with the FLP setting "Asynchronous Module Loading" and CSP?

Tags: sapui5, content-security-policy, amd, sap-fiori, ui5-tooling

The ["Browser Settings"](https://help.sap.com/docs/build-work-zone-advanced-edition/sap-build-work-zone-advanced-edition/site-settings#browser-settings) section from the "Site Settings" page of the launchpad [now allows](https://help.sap.com/whats-new/cf0cb2cb149647329b5d02aa96303f56?locale=en-US&Valid_as_Of=%3A%3Aunscheduled&Component=Cloud%20Portal%20Service%3BHTML5%20Applications%3BLaunchpad%20Service%3BSAP%20Build%20Work%20Zone,%20advanced%20edition%3BSAP%20Work%20Zone&q=asynchronous) enabling "Asynchronous Module Loading".

[image: SAP Fiori launchpad Asynchronous Module Loading switch]

But once it's enabled, some of the SAPUI5 applications or FLP plugins fail to start. The browser reports in the console:

> Failed to execute '*<JavaScript module>*.js': Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following *Content Security Policy* directive: `"script-scr * data: blob:"`.

How is the CSP topic related to the launchpad's "Asynchronous Module Loading" setting in this case and what can we do to avoid evaluating "string as JavaScript" in UI5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Cause

If "Asynchronous Module Loading" is activated, not only does SAP Fiori launchpad (FLP) bootstrap SAPUI5 with `data-sap-ui-async="true"` but serves also its HTML document with the `content-security-policy` (CSP) response header that contains a set of CSP directives **omitting** `unsafe-eval` and `unsafe-inline` from `script-src`. UI5 contents, that initiate calling `eval` or contain inline scripts, violate the CSP and thus won't be processed by the browser.

In the legacy UI5 code, `eval` is called typically due to the application synchronously fetching JS modules via deprecated APIs. For other causes, see the table below.

## Resolution

It is highly recommended to **keep the "Asynchronous Module Loading" setting enabled** which improves the overall UI5 performance in FLP (unblocked main thread) and security (stricter CSP).

UI5 has already deprecated legacy/synchronous APIs and — with the 1.96 release — largely improved the support for strict CSP. **UI5 content owners should adjust their code accordingly:**

| ❌ UI5 content violating CSP | ✅ Making UI5 content more CSP-compliant |
| --- | --- |
| Application's initial HTML document bootstrapping SAPUI5 without `data-sap-ui-async="true"` or with the debug mode activated. | Bootstrap UI5 with `data-sap-ui-async="true"` and ensure that no debug mode is activated unnecessarily. C.f. ["Is Your Application Ready for Asynchronous Loading?"](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/493a15aa978d4fe9a67ea9407166eb01) |
| Using inline scripts (`<script>...</script>`) or inline styles (`<style>...</style>`/`style="..."`). | Comply with the `script-src` and `style-src` directives that exclude `unsafe-inline` by using: - `<script src="..." ...>﻿</script>` - `data-sap-ui-onInit="module:..."` e.g. [`sap/ui/core/ComponentSupport`](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/82a0fcecc3cb427c91469bc537ebdddf). - Define styles in a separate `.css` files. |
| Using [deprecated APIs and libs](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/a87ca843bcee469f82a9072927a7dcdb) such as `jQuery.sap.*`, `Core#loadLibrary`, `Core#createComponent`, `sap.ui.component`, `sap.ui.*view`, `sap.ui.controller`, `sap.ui.*fragment`, `sap.ui.extensionpoint`, `sap.ui.commons`, `sap.ca.scfld`, `sap.ca.ui`, `sap.ui.suite`, `sap.landvisz`, `sap.ui.vtm`, `sap.zen.*`, `sap.ui.ux3`, `sap.makit`, `sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel`, `sap.ushell.Container.getService`, etc.. | Refer to the API reference to learn about newer APIs that replace the deprecated ones. When requiring JS modules, only [either `sap.ui.define` or `sap.ui.require`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62584795/5846045), and [`sap.ui.loader.config`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.loader) additionally if needed, should be used. Use the [UI5 linter](https://github.com/SAP/ui5-linter) to detect deprecated APIs. |
| Fetching resources still synchronously or indirectly referencing modules via global names [despite using non-deprecated APIs](https://community.sap.com/t5/technology-q-a/tool-to-compare-two-sapui5-versions-to-check-for-deprecated-objects/qaq-p/12808825/comment-id/4809940#M4809940). | Review the API reference, reports by the Support Assistant, **and** the console logs. You might have to [increase the log level](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/9f4d62c6648a423d85aaf2bfc2c7ddfe) e.g. via the URL parameter `sap-ui-logLevel=...` to see the relevant logs. |
| Creating the component content such as the root view, routed views, and nested views synchronously at runtime despite having them defined declaratively. | Add the marker interface [`"sap.ui.core.IAsyncContentCreation"`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.core.IAsyncContentCreation) to the [`Component.js` definition](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/27ce0e4987cd426f8fa3e60836316428) to enable creating the component content asynchronously and other benefits. |
| UI5 bundles such as `Component-preload.js` or `library-preload.js` containing JS modules that are in string. This could be, for example, due to the bundle having been generated via an outdated Grunt build task. Result: ```js "my/Module.js":'sap.ui.define([...' ``` Even when using UI5 Tooling instead, some JS modules can be still in string especially if those modules have `var`, `let`, or `const` declared in the global scope above the `sap.ui.define` call in the module definition. Result: ```js "my/Module.js":'var myGlobal...' ``` UI5 Tooling would then log the following warning in the terminal: > Module [...] requires top level scope and can only be embedded as a string (requires 'eval') | Generate the bundle by leveraging UI5 Tooling e.g. with `ui5 build -a --clean-dest`. When defining a UI5 module, avoid globals and use only `sap.ui.define` at top-level of the JS file. Result: ```js "my/Module.js":function(){//... ``` **If** the module depends on `myGlobal`: - Replace e.g. `var myGlobal` with `globalThis.myGlobal` and/or wrap the module definition in an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) if possible. - Some third party libraries (e.g. SheetJS) have to define a variable globally or must be exempted from being modified due to legal or license reasons. In this case, [exclude such third party libraries](https://sap.github.io/ui5-tooling/v3/pages/Configuration/#excludes) from the bundle. [(Sample)](https://answers.sap.com/answers/13995465/view.html) - In UI5 library development, one can also [set `requiresTopLevelScope="false"` to the affected `raw-module` within `.library`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/046e3e080ed0f4d8ba73076d9f3c0490c30801b6). Keep in mind that this approach is not publicly documented. In case the static file `locate-reuse-lib.js`, generated by SAP Fiori toos, is also included in the bundle: note that `locate-reuse-lib.js` is relevant only at development time. It is **not** supposed to be deployed together with the app. |

### Other resources that might help identifying CSP issues in UI5

#### UI5 Tooling [middleware `csp`](https://sap.github.io/ui5-tooling/pages/Server/#csp)

1. Build the app e.g. with `ui5 build --all` or `ui5 build self-contained -a`.
2. Serve the built app from the `dist` folder (Refer to [SAP/ui5-tooling issue #300](https://github.com/SAP/ui5-tooling/issues/300)).
   E.g. with `ui5 serve --config ui5-dist.yaml`.
3. Run the app with the following URL parameter:
   `index.html?sap-ui-xx-csp-policy=sap-target-level-<1 to 3>:report-only`

   - The higher `sap-target-level-<n>`, the stricter the CSP.
   - Remove `:report-only` if the browser should actually apply the CSP level.
4. Observe any CSP violation reported in the browser console.

⚠️ Currently doesn't work in combination with the custom middleware `ui5-middleware-index`.

#### Chrome DevTools

<kbd>F12</kbd> → <kbd>F1</kbd> → Select the "[Show CSP Violations view](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-89/?utm_source=devtools#csp)" checkbox from the Experiments section.

#### Q&As

- [How to avoid "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread" warning in UI5?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64461248/5846045)
- [How to detect `eval` calls when addressing UI5 modules at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75087493/5846045)

### Documentation

For more detailed information about the current state of CSP in UI5 and which restrictions there are, see the documentation topic [Content Security Policy](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/fe1a6dba940e479fb7c3bc753f92b28c).

See also the topic [Best Practices for Developers](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/28fcd55b04654977b63dacbee0552712) for other guidelines.