# How to detect `eval` calls when addressing UI5 modules at runtime?

Tags: sapui5, content-security-policy, amd, sap-fiori

As part of the preparation for the ["Asynchronous Module Loading" enablement in FLP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74959323/5846045), one of its prerequisites is making sure that no `eval` call is triggered due to the HTML document being served with the response header `Content-Security-Policy` and its directive `script-src` omitting `unsafe-eval`.

Is there a feature in UI5 that logs all `eval` calls during runtime triggered by incorrectly addressed modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Resolution

1. Open the browser console (<kbd>F12</kbd>) and ensure that "Warnings" logs are visible.
2. Start the app with the [UI5 config URL parameter](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/91f2d03b6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070) `sap-ui-xx-debugModuleLoading=true` and make sure that the debug mode is not unnecessarily enabled.
3. In the browser console, filter by "**(using eval)**".

## Example

### Given

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
  "sap/ui/comp/library",
], function(Controller, sapUiCompLib) {
  // ...
  const ValueHelpRangeOperation = sapUiCompLib.valuehelpdialog.ValueHelpRangeOperation; // enum from module "sap/ui/comp/library"
  const ValueHelpDialog = sapUiCompLib.valuehelpdialog.ValueHelpDialog; // control from module "sap/ui/comp/valuehelpdialog/ValueHelpDialog"
  return Controller.extend("my.controller.MyController", {
    onSomething: function () {
      const vhDialog = new ValueHelpDialog(/*...*/);
      // ...
    },
    // ...
  });
});
```

### Logs

[image: UI5 - debugModuleLoading 'Using Eval' reports]

### Solution

Declare the missing dependency to `"sap/ui/comp/valuehelpdialog/ValueHelpDialog"`.
No need to declare transitive dependencies that were also logged ( `: ...`).

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
  "sap/ui/comp/library",
  "sap/ui/comp/valuehelpdialog/ValueHelpDialog" // <-- Declare the module dependency
], function(Controller, sapUiCompLib, ValueHelpDialog) {
  // ...
  const ValueHelpRangeOperation = sapUiCompLib.valuehelpdialog.ValueHelpRangeOperation; // enum from module "sap/ui/comp/library"
  // const ValueHelpDialog = sapUiCompLib.valuehelpdialog.ValueHelpDialog; <-- Remove
  return Controller.extend("my.controller.MyController", {
    onSomething: function () {
      const vhDialog = new ValueHelpDialog(/*...*/);
      // ...
    },
    // ...
  });
});
```

Module name to declare as dependency can be seen in the [UI5 API reference](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api):

[image: Value Help Dialog API Refrence]